# Difference between "spelling errors" and "spelling mistakes"

Tags: word-difference

Lately, I've had a discussion with a friend. I said that *spelling mistakes* is the same thing as *spelling errors*. He doesn't agree with me. So, what's the difference? Are both correct?

Comment: Er, a *spelling error* is when there's a mistake in the spelling, while a *spelling mistake* is when there's an error in the spelling. Wait, no, that might not be it. Maybe this is it: a *spelling error* is when there's an error in the spelling, while a *spelling mistake* is when there's a mistake in the spelling. Hmm, maybe not that, but perhaps this: When a person erroneously makes a mistake (or is it "error"?) in the spelling, then that's a *spelling mistake* (or is it a *spelling error*?). Or: When a person mistakenly errors in the spelling . . . Argh! Now you got me all confused!

Answer (score 8):

I agree with your friend - a spelling error is where you regularly spell a word wrongly a spelling mistake is where you spell a word wrongly and don't notice.

> Spelling error : every time your write *friend* you write *freind* and
>   think it's correct.
>
> Spelling mistake : you write *wierd* just once and don't notice,
>   but you normally write *weird*.

Spelling mistakes are easy to make but not always easy to notice, spelling errors are unnoticeable (by you) and mean you need to learn how to spell the word correctly.

**Post comment additional information**

I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_(linguistics)#Difference_between_error_and_mistake) which seems to confirm my position.

Wikipedia contributors. "Error (linguistics)." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, 23 Oct. 2013. Web. 29 Aug. 2014.

> In linguistics, it is considered important to distinguish errors from
>   mistakes. Distinction is always made between errors and mistakes where
>   the former is seen as resulting from learner's lack of proper
>   grammatical knowledge and the latter as being failed to utilize a
>   known system correctly. ...

Comment: There's an error - sorry, a mistake - in your last sentence. ... Have you any authority (other than OP's friend!) for this distinction? I have never encountered it.

Comment: @StoneyB Only from the very slight variations in the definitions of error and mistake. It's hard to describe either without using the other but _mistake_ is nearer to a genuine accident that happens rarely, while an _error_ is due to something being wrong and happens every time that situation is met. If you learned the word 'frigid' from one single source where it was spelled 'fridgid', the original may be a mistake, the author accidentally slipped in a 'd' but now you hold the belief that 'frigid' is spelled 'fridgid', you have an error in your belief of the spelling of 'frigid'.

Comment: @StoneyB And fixed the mistake. ;)

Comment: +1 for the Wiki reference. I never thought of that! However, I'm confused if a third person is reading a content, what does he find? Spelling error or mistake! Mind it, ***'a third person'*** and not the one who wrote the content! :)

Comment: @MaulikV The same word would need to appear a few times for a third party to determine if the writer has made an error writing the wurd or made a mistake writing the word. (I'd class my 'wurd' as a mistake - It's more likely that I know  the spelling is 'word' but just hit the wrong key than I believe the correct spelling is 'wurd' but hit the wrong key twice to get what happens to be the correct spelling; 'word').

Comment: If you typed a wrong key, it's not a mistake, but a *typo!*

Comment: Unfortunately, I find it doubtful that the two parties in disagreement in the OP's post would be **linguists.** Consider, what is the difference between *subject* and *topic*? In the field of grammar, those terms have different meanings. But when used in a conversation such as: *A:"What is the subject we're arguing about?" B:"No, you should've asked 'what is the TOPIC that we're arguing about'!"* And of course, the meanings of the two terms "subject" and "topic" will be quite different from what grammarians and linguists would use. And the same goes for "errors" vs "mistakes" in the OP's post.

Comment: @MaulikV Typos are caused by mistakes, it wouldn't be a typo if I had meant to write 'wurd' believing it to be correct, then it would be just an error in my belief.

Comment: @F.E. If the OP and his friend were linguists the OP would probably not have asked the question. He now has an answer backed up by links to a number of reasonably authoritative sources (the referenced publications on the Wikipedia page) showing that there is a distinction with respect to language.

Comment: @MaulikV - I would say that a typo is a common kind of mistake.

Comment: @J.R. No! A typo is an abbreviation for [*typolographical **error***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error), not mistake. However, it's again a mistake!

Comment: @MaulikV - I know what _typo_ comes from. I still say that, in the taxonomy of errors and mistakes, typos fall on the side of mistakes.

Comment: @F.E. That aside, I don't think all linguists agree on this terminological distinction.  For instance, see [how the prominent syntactician Arnold Zwicky uses the terms](http://web.stanford.edu/~zwicky/mistakes.pdf).

Comment: I'm struggling to apply your citation to spelling. If anything, it seems like it is making the opposite distinction. Misapplying a known rule would result in regular _mistakes,_ and lack of knowledge would result in unnoticed _errors,_ no?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung The citation is not as clear as it should be. It should just say "Errors come from a learner's lack of proper grammatical knowledge" and "Mistakes come from  failing to utilize a known system correctly".  Errors are when you don't know how to spell a word correctly - mistakes are when you do know how to spell a word correctly, but still get it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

In normal use, the two phrases mean the same thing.

In a specific context a speaker or writer may say that when he says "error" he means something slightly different than when he says "mistake". But that's true of pretty much any word.